why the ts think Readonly<number> equals number
there is a strange behaviour of typescript
why the Readonly Utility using the simple type like number,string, someone know is this behavior intentional?
type Readonly<T> = {
  readonly [key in keyof T]: T[key]
}

// M equals P
type M = keyof number

type P = "toString" | "toFixed" | "toExponential" | "toPrecision" | "valueOf" | "toLocaleString"

// I want to get the type of Readonly<number>
type NumberReadonly = Readonly<number>

// why the number behaviour not like other object using readonly
type ExpectType = {

  readonly [key in P]: number[key]
  
}

// but actual the NumberReadonly equals number
type ActualType = number


Looks like you want Readonly<Number>.
